# 500Hz or higher serial port data recording

Tags: windows, visual-c++, serial-port, embedded

Hello I'm trying to read some data from the serial port and record it in the hard drive. I'm using visual C++ express, and made an application using the windows form.

The program basically sends a byte ("s") every t seconds, this trigger the device connected to the serial port to send back 3 bytes. The baud rate now is on 38400bps. The time t is controlled by the timer class of visual c++.

The problem I have is that if I set the ticking time of the timer to 1ms, the data is not recorded every 1ms, but around every 15ms. I've read that maybe the resolution of the timer is set to 15ms, but not sure about it. Anyhow, how can I make the timer event to trigger every 1ms, instead of every 15ms? or is there another way to read the serial port data faster? I'm looking for 500Hz or higher.

The device connected to the serial port is a 32bit microcontroller, which I have control over the program as well so I can easily change it, but just can't figure out another way to make this transmission.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Aside from your Windows timer issue, note that at 38400bps it takes a little more than a full millisecond to transfer 4 bytes (and that's not including any time for device turnaround or any inter-character delays).  So if you really want a transaction every millisecond you probably should increase the serial port's data rate.

Comment: @Micheal:  It is tight, but not impossible.  It simply means that the next trigger character will be sent while the last the character of the previous poll is still being received.  It does require that the incomming data is buffered, but Windows the OS does that.

Comment: Note in addition to the timer issues also that if you are using a USB-serial converter and not a real local bus serial port, you will loose a lot of time in the latency between your transmission and the device's response - another reason for having the embedded device do the timing, and windows simply receive the data, with the only requirement that it collect it often/fast enough to prevent buffer overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows is not a real-time OS, and regardless of what period your timer is set to there are no guarantees that it will be consistently maintained.  Moreover the OS clock resolution is dependent on the hardware vendor's HAL implementation and varies from system to system.  Multi-media timers have higher resolution, but the real-time guarantees are still not there.

Apart from that, you need to do a little arithmetic on the timing you are trying to achieve. At 38400,N,8,1, you can only transfer at most 3.84 characters in 1ms, so your timing is tight in any case since you are pinging with one character and expecting three characters to be returned.  You can certainly go no faster without increasing the bit rate.

A better solution would be to have the PC host send the required reporting period to the embedded target once then have the embedded target perform its own timing so that it autonomously emits data every period until the PC requests that it stop or sends a different period.  Your embedded system is far more capable of maintaining hard-real-time constraints.

Alternatively you could simply have your device perform its sample and transmit the three characters with the timing entirely determined by the transmission time of the three characters, and stream the data constantly. This will give you a sample period of 781.25us (1280Hz) without any triggering from the PC and it will be truly periodic and jitter free.  If you want a faster sample rate, simply increase the bit rate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since Windows is not real time, then I think the last option you said will be the best, but then how could I implement this on the PC? What I mean is how can I read the data from the serial port at this sampling rates (1280Hz)? I tried using the on_received interruption call, to read the buffer and store the data on memory, but cannot get all the data and sometimes the call doesn't even happen. Even the when debugging the visual studio crashes! Thanks Again!

Comment: @jegonz:  The PC will be able to process serial data at only 38400 baud without any problem.  If your PC crashes that is a problem with your PC code.  You do not need to attempt to get the data in real-time; the PC's serial buffer is substantial. Your only real problem is determining where the three-character boundaries are in order to construct the sample values from the received bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms timer resolution is about 15-20 ms. You can try multimedia timer, see timeSetEvent function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Timer precision is set by uResolution parameter (0 - maximal possible precision). In any case, you cannot get timer callback every ms - Windows is not real-time system.

Comment: You should mention timeBeginPeriod.